# Help with the water gate on Hunrath in Obduction

Tags: obduction

At the stream I threw the lever twice, which rotated the water gate to the extreme left, which then placed the propeller shaped switch out of reach.  I'm not able to walk to the opposite bank alongside the stream, and therefore I'm unable to swing the gate to the closed position, allowing me to walk across the steam.  Am I completely out of luck or is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You're fine. You do not need to walk over the stream at this point. Later on in the game you will be able to access the other side of the stream via other routes and will be able to swing it back if you so desire.

The stairs above must be dropped before you can even do this:

[image]

Comment: Won't it depend on whether the tower has been accessed yet? You need the bridge on the second level to open the tower, and if it's spun around they may be stuck. I didn't spin it to the left until the tower was accessed, so I agree it doesn't matter at that point. Idk though, maybe you don't need the tower until the end anyway, I didn't play in a linear fashion at all.

Comment: @ChristopherD. I don't think it'll let you spin it all the way around until the stairs have been dropped